# Run Doctrine 2 CLI Tools Tasks from a script run from the browser

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, php

A little background information: I am working on integrating Doctrine into a CodeIgniter application. I have it working, but I would like to be able to run the Doctrine command line (CLI) tasks from the browser, i.e. not from the command line script.

The reason I desire this is because I will be running Doctrine and CodeIgniter on a shared hosting package where I will not have command line access.

This seems like a very basic feature, but is not readily available with Doctrine 2.

My last-ditch effort will be going into the command line tool and figuring out how the tasks are being executed then duplicating that code in a CodeIgniter controller.

If there is any simpler way to do this, please let me know.

Thanks!

[Unanswered duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5986509/52749) posted a while back.

Comment: I've just posted an answer on the duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28788665/3132919

Answer (score 1):

For the following

```
$doctrine = \Zend_Registry::get('doctrine');
$em = $doctrine->getEntityManager();
$tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($em);
```

Get the SQL to update the current schema:

```
$sqlArray = $tool->getUpdateSchemaSql($em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata());
```

Update the schema with the current metadata

```
$res = $tool->updateSchema($em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata());
```

Create the schema.

```
$res = $tool->createSchema($em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata());
```

This belongs in an install script.  Just create and verify the db connection

```
$conn = $doctrine->getConnection();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
try {
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql); // Simple (too simple?)
    die('Already installed');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Table not found, continue
}
```

Then create your schema.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to try to run the command-line tools without a command-line.

However, you can do it yourself in scripts pretty simply.  For instance, if you wanted to do things that orm:schema-tool:* does, you'd [start here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/tools.html#database-schema-generation)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the input. Any particular reason why I wouldn't want to do the command-line tasks without a command-line?

Comment: Well, upon reflection, I suppose you could.  But for my money I'd rather not deal with parsing command-line output, etc, if it's easy drive the underlying API itself.  I suppose it depends on what you want to do.  If you want to go the command-line route, your typical exec (exec(), system(), shell_exec()...) ought to be sufficient.  Of course, if your shared host doesn't give you a shell, they may have such functions disabled.